# Creating a program that asks for a password and checks if its correct or not

Tags: java, loops, methods

this is some practice i am doing for my midterm tomorrow. I cant seem to find the problem with my code, this is the question:

> Having a secure password is a very important practice, when much of our information
>       is stored online. Write a program that validates a new password, following these
>       rules:
>
> • The password must be at least 8 characters long.
>
> • The password must have at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter
>
> • The password must have at least one digit.
>
> Write a program that asks for a password, then asks again to confirm it. If the
>       passwords don’t match or the rules are not fulfilled, prompt again. Your program
>       should include a method that checks whether a password is valid.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author HP Laptop
 */
public class PasswordValidation {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter password : ");
        String password = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
        String confirm = in.nextLine();
        boolean condition;
        condition = isValid(password);
        while (!password.equals(confirm) && (!condition)) {
            System.out.println("The password is invalid");
            System.out.print("Please enter the password again : ");
            String Password = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
            String Confirm = in.nextLine();


        }
        if (isValid(password)) {
            System.out.println("The password is valid");
        /*} else {
            System.out.println("The password is not valid");
            System.out.print("Please enter the password again : ");
            String Password = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
            String Confirm = in.nextLine();
        }*/
    }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String password) {

        if (password.length() < 8) {
            return false;
        } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i))) {
            }
        }


        for (int b = 0; b < password.length(); b++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(b))) {
            }
        }

        for (int c = 0; c < password.length(); c++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(password.charAt(c))) {
            }

        }

        return true;


    }
}
}
```

Error is:

I enter a name less than 8 digits and it would say its valid when its not, also when its all valid and right, it doesn't print that its valid.

Comment: What are those 3 for loops doing?

Comment: @GPRathour checking each condition.

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: `condition` is an icky variable name.

Comment: user3821797: as GPRathour and @Dave Newton have pointed out, I believe if your style was neater then you'd have a much easier time debugging this code. I suggest you name variable names more useful and have many small functions that each do a very specific task.

Answer (score 1):

@user3821797: I slightly modified your isValid method. Go through it and make sure you understand what I did. If you have any questions at all, please comment here and I'll help you out.

```
    public static boolean isValid(String password) {
    Boolean atleastOneUpper = false;
    Boolean atleastOneLower = false;
    Boolean atleastOneDigit = false;

    if (password.length() < 8) { // If its less then 8 characters, its automatically not valid
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) { // Lets iterate over only once. Saving time
        if (Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i))) {
            atleastOneUpper = true;
        }
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i))) {
            atleastOneLower = true;
        }
        else if (Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))) {
            atleastOneDigit = true;
        }
    }

    return (atleastOneUpper && atleastOneLower && atleastOneDigit); // Return true IFF the password is atleast eight characters long, has atleast one upper, lower and digit
}
```

Comment: thank you my friend, but now if its valid it wont print valid, it prints invalid.

Comment: I suggest you look at this line "while (!password.equals(confirm) && (!condition))". I believe you want "||" instead of "&&". You want to tell them their password is incorrect if what they entered does not match what they confirmed OR if what they entered it not valid.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
while (!password.equals(confirm) && (!condition)) {
```

you want

```
while (!password.equals(confirm) || (!condition)) {
```

Since the password is invalid if either `isValid(password)` returned false, or the confirmed password is different than the original typed password.

Your current code won't pass the while condition if `password.equals(confirm)`, even though condition is false (due to the password being to short).

In addition, your while loop should call `condition = isValid(password);` again after the password and confirmed password are re-typed. Otherwise, the while loop would never exit.

So either write :

```
    condition = isValid(password);
    while (!password.equals(confirm) || (!condition)) {
        System.out.println("The password is invalid");
        System.out.print("Please enter the password again : ");
        String Password = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
        String Confirm = in.nextLine();
        condition = isValid(password);
    }
```

Or more elegantly :

```
    while (!password.equals(confirm) || !isValid(password)) {
        System.out.println("The password is invalid");
        System.out.print("Please enter the password again : ");
        String Password = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
        String Confirm = in.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: worked thank you, now when i enter a correct password it says invalid

Comment: @user3821797 What password did you enter? Did you enter the same password twice?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a few issues here, but the one that stands out is this:

```
while (!password.equals(confirm) && (!condition)) {
```

If I type the password "abc" and confirmation as "abc", then `!password.equals(confirm)` is `false`.  I think you want this to be:

```
while (!password.equals(confirm) || (!condition)) {
```

Because you want to repeat this behavior whenever the password doesn't match *or* is invalid.

This is also incorrect:

```
    condition = isValid(password);
    while (!password.equals(confirm) && (!condition)) {
        System.out.println("The password is invalid");
        System.out.print("Please enter the password again : ");
        String Password = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
        String Confirm = in.nextLine();
    }
```

You never re-check `isValid`, and you're storing the re-entered password and confirmation in new variables (scoped to the loop) called `Password` and `Confirm`.  Try assigning these directly to your existing variables and re-calling `isValid`:

```
    condition = isValid(password);
    while (!password.equals(confirm) && (!condition)) {
        System.out.println("The password is invalid");
        System.out.print("Please enter the password again : ");
        password = in.nextLine(); // <-- HERE
        System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
        confirm = in.nextLine(); // <-- HERE

        condition = isValid(password); // <-- HERE
    }
```

Comment: right, thanks it worked but still now i enter a correct password, it says its incorrect.

Comment: Updated for the second issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked above code and went through small modification and have tested over it and it is not accepting the password with less than 8 digits.And no need to add more variables.
Go through it..

```
condition = isValid(password);
    while (!password.equals(confirm) && (!condition)) {
        System.out.println("The password is invalid");
        System.out.print("Please enter the password again : ");
        String Password = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please re-enter the password to confirm : ");
        String Confirm = in.nextLine();
        password = Password;
        confirm = Confirm;
        condition = isValid(password);
   }
```